# SIGABRT with Xcode using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt

So something happened with my Xcode where I continuously keep getting Thread 1 SIGABRT error.

I have literally tried what every message board has suggested, and don't know where to turn to next. I know its not an issue with outlets, because I ensured there was no outlet on the storyboard. I tried opening past projects (which worked perfectly fine in the past) but they too crashed with this error. It seems like there is something wrong with Xcode itself. It will always crash any project that has any elements on the storyboard.

Could anyone help and make sense of this?

```
2016-08-17 18:58:58.482 wazSUP[2002:41440] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't set default ACL before Parse is initialized.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6f1d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110624deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e6f1cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   wazSUP                              0x000000010dd40f5a +[PFACL setDefaultACL:withAccessForCurrentUser:] + 175
    4   wazSUP                              0x000000010dd35bf1 _TFC6wazSUP11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPs9AnyObject____Sb + 401
    5   wazSUP                              0x000000010dd362a4 _TToFC6wazSUP11AppDelegate11applicationfTCSo13UIApplication29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsGSqGVs10DictionaryCSo8NSObjectPs9AnyObject____Sb + 180
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010f09f9ac -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 272
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010f0a0c0d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3415
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f0a7568 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f0a4714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111c7c8c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111c7c741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
    12  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000111c7caca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e617301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e60d22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e60c6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e60c0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010f0a3f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010f0a8f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    19  wazSUP                              0x000000010dd36f22 main + 114
    20  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011112b92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have not seen your code so I do not know exactly what to do to fix it but I can explain Thread 1 SIGABRT to you. 
The bug can be caused in 2 ways:

If you have the code for an IBOUTLET but deleted the connection from the view controller to the program or Vice Versa it will cause the bug

Also doing `self.addChild(nodeName)` multiple times to the same node without removing between the 2 occurrences can cause it as well.

Hope this helped.